# "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'attributes')" error in React (with Strapi)

Tags: javascript, react-native, strapi

I'm unable to render items from my Strapi collection. Following is the code I wrote to get "Photo" of my uploaded products in Strapi.

```js
<Image
  style={{ height: 150, resizeMode: "cover" }}
  source={{
      uri: "http://localhost:1337" + item.Photo.data[0].attributes.url,  //Home.js:180
  }}
/>
```

[image: 1]

I'm also getting an

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined" at (VM110:2), and
> "The above error occurred in the  component:" at
> (index.js:1)

Comment: `item.Photo.data[0]` is clearly undefined - so `item.Photo.data` is either not an array or is an empty array. But you don't give us nearly enough context to diagnose the problem beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the populate parameter when making your request?
By default Strapi doesn’t include media in its REST API response.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).